# Does Android theme-color and favicon work with https?

Tags: android, google-chrome

In Chrome for Android on Lollipop, you can set a meta theme-color tag and favicon: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android?hl=en

My code:

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="//static.rizzo.co.uk/images/favicon_192.png">

<meta name="theme-color" content="#95c676">
```

This works for me on parts of the site that are http but as soon as it goes to https it loses the theme-color and favicon for the rest of the session.

I have tried the theme-color and favicon separately but can get neither to work with https.  The favicon is available on https as well as http.  Has anyone used these successfully with https or had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had the same issue, turns out it was a caching problem that somehow was fixed when I used android remote debugging (caching only the head tag?).

Anyway, it should work. You can try copy pasting the html in this page to your https server: http://useragentman.com/tests/theme-color/?test

or attach the following script (from useragentman, in case page is down):

```
<script>
    var $themeColor = document.querySelector("meta[name='theme-color']");
    function startAnim() {
        if ($themeColor.content === '#ff0000') {
            $themeColor.content = '#ffffff';
        } else {
            $themeColor.content = '#ff0000';
        }
        setTimeout(startAnim, 500);
    }
    startAnim();
</script>
```